# SQL Query to return data for the first of every month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to find the number of staff in a department at the start of each month, for the last 12 months.

I can get the desired output using 12 separate queries and `UNION ALL` similar to below:

---

```
SELECT
    o.DEP_ID
   ,COUNT(o.STAFF_ID) STAFF_COUNT
   ,TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON') EFFECTIVE_DATE
FROM
    OCCUPANCIES o
WHERE
    o.START_DATE <= TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON')
AND o.END_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON')
GROUP BY
    o.DEP_ID
   ,TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON')
UNION ALL
SELECT
    o.DEP_ID
   ,COUNT(o.STAFF_ID) STAFF_COUNT
   ,ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON'),-1) EFFECTIVE_DATE
FROM
    OCCUPANCIES o
WHERE
    o.START_DATE <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON'),-1)
AND o.END_DATE >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON'),-1)
GROUP BY
    o.DEP_ID
   ,ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON'),-1)
```

---

**This gives me output similar to the following:**

---

[image: output]

---

Unfortunately my real query is very long, and editing it is becoming unwieldy to say the least because I am making the same changes in 12 places each time.

**Is there a way of doing this in a single SELECT statement?**

EDIT: I have uploaded an example to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9318b/1)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, hit "post" too soon. Have added the question and a SQL Fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a list of effective dates and use it in your query

```
SELECT
    o.DEP_ID
   ,COUNT(o.STAFF_ID) STAFF_COUNT
   ,dt.EFFECTIVE_DATE
FROM
    OCCUPANCIES o,

    (SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON'), 1-LEVEL) EFFECTIVE_DATE 
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <=12) dt
WHERE
    dt.EFFECTIVE_DATE BETWEEN o.START_DATE AND o.END_DATE
GROUP BY
    o.DEP_ID
   ,dt.EFFECTIVE_DATE
```

Comment: I wish I could add more than one vote! Genius. I just wish I had any idea how it worked....

Comment: Here are some useful links on series generation
http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-11821.html
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques

Comment: For anyone else finding this answer, here is the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9318b/16